# How to copy multi file excel and paste to one file excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
srcPath = @textBox1.Text;
srcxlApp = new Excel.Application();
srcworkBook = srcxlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcPath);
srcworkSheet = srcworkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
srcrange = srcworkSheet.UsedRange;
srcrange.Copy(Type.Missing);
```

How to copy multi file excel and paste to one file excel in C#

Comment: Hi user2336686, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You include some code in your question - can you describe more fully how far you've got with your code so far, and what goes wrong when you run it?

Comment: .......................................

Comment: copy one file i need copy multi file excel and paste in one file

Comment: When you've got more information to add to your question, it's better to not just put it as a comment; if you edit your question to include the new information, it's clearer for any reader because everything they need to read is in one place.